# Julia: ImplictPlots in a loop: setting colors

Tags: julia, julia-plots

How can I assign colors with `implicit_plot`?

```
using ImplicitPlots, Plots
v = [(x,y) -> (x+3)*(y^3-7)+18, (x,y) -> sin(y*exp(x)-1)]
p = plot()
for f in v 
    implicit_plot!(f; xlims = (-1, 3), ylims = (-1, 2), framestyle = :origin, lc = [:red, :blue])
end
p
```

[image: implicitplots]

I expected something along the lines of:

```
lc = [:red, :blue]
for (i, f) in enumerate (v)
    implicit_plot!(f; xlims = (-1, 3), ylims = (-1, 2), lc = lc[i])
end
```

How can I pass a gradient of blue colors for the second function? (I can pass `lc = :blues` but that makes the first line blue as well.)

Bonus question: Can I pass a vector or tuple to `implicit_plot`? I guess it's not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it does not work? I tried

```
lc = [:red, :blue]
for (i, f) in enumerate(v)
    implicit_plot!(f; xlims = (-1, 3), ylims = (-1, 2), lc = lc[i])
end
```

and I got

[image]

(You had an extra space in `enumerate`  which maybe threw you off?)

Not sure about the tuple of functions.

Comment: Oh how strange! Well thanks for your timely answer! Would you know how to pass a gradient to the "blues" ? I got this to work: `lc = :blues`, but I'd like the first one to stay red. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure but replacing `:blue` with `:blues` should not affect the red color. Also, trying `lc = [:red, [:blue :green]]` shows that the order in which the lines are drawn might not be what you expect anyway...

Comment: Wow. The mind boggles Benoît, the mind boggles. Thanks! :-)